# JAXB Example in camel

Tags: apache-camel

Can any one provide me simple example in camel with JAXB using spring XML? I searched on net but did not find anything.

I just want to create simple Student class with fields name, id and convert it into xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what in particular you're struggling with, but here are some snippets:

```html
<util:map id="jaxbNamespacePrefixMap">
  <!-- In my case, we dont want a prefix for our namespace; YMMV -->
  <entry key="http://www.nmcourts.gov" value=""/>
</util:map> 

<marshal>
  <jaxb prettyPrint="true" contextPath="generated.gov.nmcourts.ecitation.shared.odyssey" 
        partClass="generated.gov.nmcourts.ecitation.shared.odyssey.NMCitationEFileBatch" partNamespace="EFileBatch"
        namespacePrefixRef="jaxbNamespacePrefixMap"/>
</marshal>

<unmarshal>
  <jaxb prettyPrint="true" contextPath="generated.gov.nmcourts.ecitation.shared.odyssey"
        partClass="generated.gov.nmcourts.ecitation.shared.odyssey.NMCitationEFileBatch"
        partNamespace="EFileBatch" namespacePrefixRef="jaxbNamespacePrefixMap" />
</unmarshal>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you need exactly?

http://camel.apache.org/jaxb shows perfectly well how to marshal to xml via spring.